# Using Arsenal's summary(table_by()) to count over multiple variables

Tags: function, count, environment-variables, summary

I am working with a dataset for a research project and am trying to use Arsenal's summary function to create a descriptive table of characteristics of the intervention and control groups. A sample data set is as follows:

```
idx <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
class <- c("control","control","control","intervention","intervention","intervention")
risk1 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"Age",NA)
risk2 <- c("Age","Age","Multiparity","Multiparity","Multiparity","Age")
fake_data <- data.frame(idx,class,risk1,risk2)
```

I would like the summary data to show that 4 subjects have the risk factor of Age and 3 have the risk factor of multiparity.

Previously, these Risk 1 and Risk 2 were 1 variable, "Risk" with a list of multiple risk factors for some subjects (separated by a variety of punctuation--plus signs, commas, etc.), and I used stringr to create 2 variables. What I didn't anticipate is how this would affect counts when I ran the following code:

```
library(arsenal)
summary(tableby(class ~ risk1 + risk2, data=fake_data))
```

Is there a way to write the function within tableby so that risk1 & risk2 are combined into a single variable (abstract or concrete) for counting? I considered making the data long form, i.e. creating 2 rows of data for the subjects with 2 risk factors, but that would change the denominator for proportions (i.e., it would appear that 4/7 subjects, instead of 4/6, have the risk factor of age.

I like the appearance and functionality of arsenal's summary function so I'd prefer to use it, but if you have an idea of a better package, I am open to it. I am also open to keeping my original unsplit "Risk" variable and working from there, if anyone has suggestions to succeed in that format.